# Jquery adding class to span or div with unknown ID

Tags: jquery

Apologies for a newbie question but I wonder what the best way is to do the following?

I have a page with two forms on, both of which collapse / expand to reveal their fields. This is the basic code for the forms in their collapsed state:

```
<div class="myForms">
    <span class="collapsed" id="form1">Form 1</span>
    <div id="target-form1" class="collapsed_content" style="display: none;">
    .
    *(form 1 code in here)*
    .
    <span class="collapsed" id="form2">Form 2</span>
    <div id="target-form2" class="collapsed_content" style="display: none;">
    .
    *(form 2 code in here)*
    .
</div>
```

If one of the forms is clicked on to expand, the following two things happen:
(1) the class 'open' is added to the span for that form
(2) the style for the form div is changed to 'display:block'

So if you, for example, click Form 1 you end up with this:

```
<div class="myForms">
    <span class="collapsed open" id="form1">Form 1</span>
    <div id="target-form1" class="collapsed_content" style="display: block;">
    .
    *(form 1 code in here)*
    .
    <span class="collapsed" id="form2">Form 2</span>
    <div id="target-form2" class="collapsed_content" style="display: none;">
    .
    *(form 2 code in here)*
    .
</div>
```

Rather than 'form1', 'form2' etc the actual id for each form is a random id generated by the collapse/expand plugin (Collapse-O-Matic) (e.g. 'id7722'). The div id is the same with 'target-' added to the front (e.g. 'target-id7722').

Now my problem is that when I open, say, Form 1, enter some data and then click on the form's Update button, the form collapses (presumably it's doing some sort of refresh that restores it to the state it was when the page loaded (i.e. collapsed)). But, I need the form to refresh and automatically expand again so the contents are immediately visible.

I can do it ok on Form 1 using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   setTimeout("jQuery('span#form1').addClass('open');",1);
   setTimeout("jQuery('#target-form1').css('display','block');",1);
</script>
```

...but I need a generic bit of JQuery that will do the above for whichever form has had it's Update button clicked. I don't need to test for which form on the page is open, as the form plugin (Formidable Forms) allows me to enter the code snippet just given above into each form I create. I just need to end up with the JQuery version of this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   setTimeout("jQuery('span id for the current form').addClass('colomat-close');",1);
   setTimeout("jQuery('div id for the current form').css('display','block');",1);
</script>
```

...rather than hardcoding in the form id into the span and div?

Comment: Where is the update button?  If it's a direct descendant of the form, you could use something like `$(this).parent()`

Comment: Does the `Update` button causes a `postback`? Because you will have to pass the `form id` in this case ...

Comment: @sideroxylon: the update button is within the target-form1 or target form2 div

Comment: Then attach a click function to the button and use `$(this).parents('form')` as your selector in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="myForms">
    <span class="collapsed" id="form1" onclick="$(this).next().addClass('blabla');">Form 1</span>
    <div id="target-form1" class="collapsed_content" style="display: none;"'>
</div>
```

Is it possible solution?

Or you can:

```
$(document).on('click', 'span.collapsed', function(){
  $(this).next().addClass('blabla');
});
```